# Max parallel http requests in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, xmlhttprequest

Currently Chrome has a limit of 6 connections per host name, and a max of 10 connections.

What happens when the number of http requests exceeds the limit in Chrome?

The extra http requests will be queued or they will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection limit is reached, further requests will wait until connections free up.